# iOS In App Purchases and other content deleted every few days

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Every few days, all in app purchases disappear. I have to go into each app and use the "Restore Purchases" option to get everything back.

Also:

- My alarms keep being deleted - the alarm page is just blank and I have to add them again.
- Passwords/Log in states for apps are being lost - for example I have to log into Instagram, etc, every few days.

It feels like some sort of caching/preferences issue, stuff getting deleted when it shouldn't be? I have an iPhone 7, 128GB, with 35GB free space.

This has never happened in 10 years of using iPhones, and as far as I can recall nothing has changed, i.e., no updates or anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: About the passwords/login states for apps, Could it be possible that this is related your current region settings? Could you check if the data in Settings > General > Language & Region is correct?

Comment: @Jules All that seems correct :/

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if Apple ID is correct in Settings > iTunes & App Store, as below pic, check if the AUTOMATIC DOWNLOADS optionns are checked? Well I prefer to cancel all of them.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, and thanks for your contribution! Could you please give a bit more background on your answer? For example: how would an incorrect Apple ID cause in-app purchases to vanish regularly? Or, how could an Apple ID possibly cause an app to lose its persistent state?